# Is anyone have memory leaks using cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I am detecin a memory leak particularily in the startAnimation method in the director object.

```
- (void) startAnimation
{
    if ( gettimeofday( &lastUpdate, NULL) != 0 ) {
        CCLOG(@"cocos2d: DisplayLinkDirector: Error on gettimeofday");
    }

    // approximate frame rate
    // assumes device refreshes at 60 fps
    int frameInterval   = (int) floor(animationInterval * 60.0f);

    CCLOG(@"cocos2d: Frame interval: %d", frameInterval);

    displayLink = [NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(preMainLoop:)];
    [displayLink setFrameInterval:frameInterval];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

It leaks at : `[NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(preMainLoop:)];`

This only occurs in the device and not in the simulator.
Not sure if anyone else is getting this?

Comment: Are you using the new 0.9.0 alpha version of cocos2d?

I cannot find this in 0.8.2

Comment: I am using 0.8.2, this only occurs when i am compiling it into the actual device and not in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You really should update to the latest build, there are quite some improvements with 0.99